# string manipulations using Spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have the following Spark scala dataframe.

```
val someDF = Seq(
  (1, "bat",1.3222),
  (4, "cbat",1.40222),
  (3, "horse",1.501212)
).toDF("number", "word","value")
```

I created a User Defined Function (UDF) to create a new variable as follows :

Logic : if words equals bat then value else zero.

```
  import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col}
    val func1 = udf( (s:String ,y:Double) => if(s.contains("bat")) y else 0 )
    func1(col("word"),col("value"))

+------+-----+-------+
|number| word|cal_var|
+------+-----+-------+
|     1|  bat| 1.3222|
|     4| cbat|1.40222|
|     3|horse|    0.0|
+------+-----+-------+
```

Here to check the equality i used `contains` function . Because of that i am getting the incorrect output  .
My desired output should be like this :

```
+------+-----+-------+
|number| word|cal_var|
+------+-----+-------+
|     1|  bat| 1.3222|
|     4| cbat|    0.0|
|     3|horse|    0.0|
+------+-----+-------+
```

Can anyone help me to figure out the correct string function that i should use to check the equality ?

Thank you

Comment: You can achieve it more effective with spark sql:
`someDF.select(when(col("word") === "bat",col("cal_var")).otherwise(0))`

Comment: ^no need to use udf, use spark inbuilt when, otherwise statements and instead of contains use =='bat'

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution is to use `equals` method rather than `contains`. `contains` checks whether string `bat` is present anywhere in the given string `s` and not the equality. The code is shown below:

```
scala> someDF.show
+------+-----+--------+
|number| word|   value|
+------+-----+--------+
|     1|  bat|  1.3222|
|     4| cbat| 1.40222|
|     3|horse|1.501212|
+------+-----+--------+


scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

scala> val func1 = udf( (s:String ,y:Double) => if(s.equals("bat")) y else 0 )
func1: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction = UserDefinedFunction(<function2>,DoubleType,Some(List(StringType, DoubleType)))

scala> someDF.withColumn("col_var", func1(col("word"),col("value"))).drop("value").show
+------+-----+-------+
|number| word|col_var|
+------+-----+-------+
|     1|  bat| 1.3222|
|     4| cbat|    0.0|
|     3|horse|    0.0|
+------+-----+-------+
```

Let me know if it helps!!

Answer (score 4):

Try to avoid using UDF's as it gives poor performance,

Another approach:

```
val someDF = Seq(
            (1, "bat",1.3222),
            (4, "cbat",1.40222),
            (3, "horse",1.501212)
          ).toDF("number", "word","value")

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
        
someDF.show

+------+-----+--------+
|number| word|   value|
+------+-----+--------+
|     1|  bat|  1.3222|
|     4| cbat| 1.40222|
|     3|horse|1.501212|
+------+-----+--------+

someDF.withColumn("value",when('word === "bat",'value).otherwise(0)).show()
+------+-----+------+
|number| word| value|
+------+-----+------+
|     1|  bat|1.3222|
|     4| cbat|   0.0|
|     3|horse|   0.0|
+------+-----+------+
```

Comment: can you please explain why udf gives poor performance ..

Comment: Please check this link:  https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/content/spark-sql-udfs-blackbox.html